# Truncate table failed with error "Could not drop constraint" in SSIS package in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, truncate

SSIS package was running fine but suddenly started getting error today.
Not sure what went wrong.

[image: Error]

Here is the table structure

[image: Table structure]

Changed the script based on @Tyron78 suggestions but still getting error

> Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Truncate table AuditEventParameter
> IF OBJECT_ID('d..." failed with the following error: "Cannot truncate table 'AuditEvent' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

```
    Truncate table AuditEventParameter
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter', 'FK') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditEventParameter] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter
    Truncate table AuditEvent
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditEventParameter]  WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter] FOREIGN KEY([eventID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AuditEvent] ([eventID])
```

Comment: and did it work the next time you ran it? I guess there was a prior issue where the constraint was not recreated, and the next time your SSIS ran. it couldn't find it to drop it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, No. It is failing after that. I am bit lost here how come I suddenly started getting error in the first place. SSIS package was running smoothly prior to this error. And how come this was not recreated when the package ran next. Do you think there is any error in the script.

Comment: _how come this was not recreated when the package ran next_ because it probably managed to recreate the constraint in one run so the next run, it could drop it withuot an error.

Answer (score 1):

Before dropping any object, I would strongly recommend to check for it's existence first. Try the following instead of your drop:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter', 'FK') IS NOT NULL
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditEventParameter] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter
```

As mentioned in a previous comment, it looks as if your package crashed somewhere after the drop and before the recreate in the past - so the package now trys to drop a constraint which doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Hi @Tyron78, What could be the possibilities of crash? Suddenly, why it got crashed? Could you please show me complete solution. Thank you

Comment: @RjLearn it is impossible for us to tell what crashed during your previous execution! There are a ton of possibilities: an error during `Truncate table AuditEvent`, some server issues, the cancellation of the executed package... anything can lead to this behaviour. Therefore you should ALWAYS check if an object exists before trying to drop it. For the "full solution" simply replace `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditEventParameter] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter]` in your code with the code I posted...

Comment: My SSIS package is still going to fail if the `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FK_AuditEvent_AuditEventParameter', 'FK') IS NOT NULL`  is null. Am I right?

Comment: No, it will simply not perform the DROP statement and move on to the next statement

Comment: Thank you, @Tyron78. I will clean the table use this `If` statement into my query

Comment: @RjLearn if this solves your problem it would be nice if you could accept the answer.